# Linked list in C - first node data incorrect and can't figure it out

Tags: c, multithreading, list, linked-list

I have a multithreaded C program, where one thread creates random times and numbers, and stores them in a sorted linked list, and the second thread compares the the time in the first node to the current system time and deletes the node whenever the times are equal. However, 0 0 gets added to the linked list first, and I can't find where. It's not being added in the insert function as far as I can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the relevant code:

```
#include <pthread.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h> 

pthread_mutex_t count_mutex;

/* Link list node */
struct node
{
    int roomNo;
    time_t time;
    struct node* next;
};

void printList(struct node *node)
{
  while(node!=NULL)
  {
    printf("%d ", node->roomNo);
    printf("%d\n ", node->time);
    node = node->next;
  }
}

/* Function to insert a node at the beginging of the linked list */
void insert(struct node** head_ref, int new_room, time_t new_time)
{
  /* allocate node */
  struct node* new_node =
  (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  /* put in the data  */
  new_node->roomNo  = new_room;
  new_node->time  = new_time;

  /* link the old list off the new node */
  new_node->next = (*head_ref);    

  /* move the head to point to the new node */
  (*head_ref)    = new_node;
    MergeSort(&(*head_ref));
} 


/* sorts the linked list by changing next pointers (not data) */
void MergeSort(struct node** headRef)
{
  struct node* head = *headRef;
  struct node* a;
  struct node* b;

  /* Base case -- length 0 or 1 */
  if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL))
  {
     return;
  }

    /* Split head into 'a' and 'b' sublists */
  FrontBackSplit(head, &a, &b); 

  /* Recursively sort the sublists */
  MergeSort(&a);
  MergeSort(&b);

  /* answer = merge the two sorted lists together */
  *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b);
}


struct node* SortedMerge(struct node* a, struct node* b)
{
  struct node* result = NULL;

  /* Base cases */
  if (a == NULL)
    return(b);
  else if (b==NULL)
    return(a);

  /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
  if (a->time <= b->time)
  {
    result = a;
    result->next = SortedMerge(a->next, b);
  }
  else
  {
    result = b;
    result->next = SortedMerge(a, b->next);
  }
  return(result);
 }


void FrontBackSplit(struct node* source,
                     struct node** frontRef, struct node** backRef)
{
  struct node* fast;
  struct node* slow;
  if (source==NULL || source->next==NULL)
  {
    /* length < 2 cases */
    *frontRef = source;
    *backRef = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
    slow = source;
    fast = source->next;

    /* Advance 'fast' two nodes, and advance 'slow' one node */
    while (fast != NULL)
    {
       fast = fast->next;
      if (fast != NULL)
      {
        slow = slow->next;
        fast = fast->next;
      }
    }

    /* 'slow' is before the midpoint in the list, so split it in two
     at that point. */
    *frontRef = source;
    *backRef = slow->next;
    slow->next = NULL;
  }
}

void * addThread(void *n) 
{  
  struct node *llnode = n;
  int i;
        for(i = 0; i <4; i++)
    { 
             pthread_mutex_lock(&count_mutex);
             printf("Adding node.\n");
             insert(&llnode, getRandRoom(), getRandTime());
     sleep(1);
             printf("the list is...\n");
             printList(llnode);
             pthread_mutex_unlock(&count_mutex);
    }
}

struct node* head;

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, ctrlc_catch);

    pthread_t addWakeup, makeWakeup;

    pthread_create(&addWakeup, NULL, addThread, (void*)&head);
    pthread_create(&makeWakeup, NULL, wakeThread, (void*)&head);

    pthread_join(addWakeup, NULL);
    pthread_join(makeWakeup, NULL);

      return 0;
}
```

Example output is:

```
Adding node.
the list is...
0 0
 4000 1323882918
 Adding node.
the list is...
 0 0
 809 1323882890
 4000 1323882918
 Adding node.
the list is...
0 0
 809 1323882890
 7617 1323882908
 4000 1323882918
 Adding node.
the list is...
0 0
 809 1323882890
 7617 1323882908
 4000 1323882918
 4426 1323882926
```

Comment: Could you show us the output of this program and the expected output?

Comment: You should not use the `void *` type because you know those parameters will be of type `struct node *`.  Using `void *` prevents the compiler from doing some checking for you, but I don't think it would cause the problem you are asking about.

Comment: Could you show us the source code of MergeSort?  This is necessary to debug your program.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your problem, but why are you inserting at the head if you want to maintain a sorted list?

Comment: I've edited to post to include the MergeSore code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is most likely due to passing address of `head` (i.e. ~`struct node**`) instead of `head`(i.e. `struct node*`) to the thread function where `void *` is typecast to `struct node*`. Change this call `pthread_create(&addWakeup, NULL, addThread, (void*)&head);` to `pthread_create(&addWakeup, NULL, addThread, (void*)head);` & next call also on similar lines. *Unfortunately* you were not seeing a crash in the current case. On my system I observed that initializing `head` to `NULL` was crashing the program. Similar suggestion has already been provided by @wildplasser. Try this change out and check the list printed.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I never would have seen that! :)

Answer (score 1):

While it may exist in code not shown, the code may need a call to [pthread_mutex_init](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_init) to initialize the mutex. It is possible that the contents of the variable `count_mutex` are initialized "by chance" to values that will actually work, but it would not be good to rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

Your function addthread creates a local copy `llnode` of its argument `n`, and uses a pointer to `llnode` to call insert(). Insert can alter `llnode`, but that change will only affect the local copy.

You should change addThread to take an argument of type `struct node**`, instead of `struct node*`.